# Check if value is in an array created from a txt file

Tags: php

I want to check if a value is in array created from a text file (a list of email addresses).
Why neither of these solutions work? (foreach or in_array)
(I've tried printing the array $text and it's ok, no problem coming from file.txt, same thing with $search)

```
    $myfile = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    while(!feof($myfile)) {
        $text[] = fgets($myfile);
    }
    fclose($myfile);
 
   $search=$_POST['something'];

    foreach ($text as $val) {
        if (strpos($search, $val) !== FALSE) {
            echo "oK";
        }
    }
```

/* OR * /

if (in_array($search, $text)) {
echo "OK"; }

Comment: have you tried `in_array( $search, file('file.txt') )` - as `file` will return an array so it should be fairly simple to test if an item exists

Comment: doesn't seem to work either :-(

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would not put an entire file input input into an array as its a waste of memory you're already using reading from a file (specially if its large).

You can instead do your "like" condition inside of the loop. I would use `str_contains` for ease if your PHP version supports it. Build an array based on found results.

```
if (!isset($_POST['something'])) die('Missing search term');

# TODO: Handle this Exception better
$emails = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file");

$similarEmails = [];

while(!feof($emails))
    if (str_contains(($line = fgets($emails)), $_POST['something']))
        $similarEmails[] = $line;

fclose($emails);
```

References:

- [`str_contains`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php)

Comment: shouldn't it be `while(!feof($emails))` ?

Comment: Too much copy and pasting from the OP, thanks @argyx - updated

Comment: ok:) Not working though... Might it be a format problem coming from the txt file?